# Android ArrayAdapters convertviews tag null after update

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to update my custom ArrayAdapter, but after calling updateListArray getView is called and the convertview is not null but the tag is null, giving me errors. If I make an extra null check and set a new viewholder it simply shows the wrong content.
I simply can't figure out why this gives me problems, I have following in code:

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
        private ArrayList<Item> mListItems;

        public CustomAdapter (Context context, int rowResourceId, ArrayList<Item> items) {
            super(context, rowResourceId, items);
            mListItems = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null) {
                // setup holder
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

                holder.mEventStart = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_date);
                holder.mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_artist);
                holder.mSubTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_description);

                holder.mImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_artist_image);
                holder.mScene = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_scene_image);
                holder.mStatus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_new);
                holder.mRowParent = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_parent);

            } else {
                // get existing row view
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            //setup row view content
            if(!mListItems.isEmpty()) {
//set content
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        public void updateListArray(ArrayList<Item> list) {
            this.clear();
            for(Item item : list) {
                this.add(item);
            }
            mListItems = list;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Where do you set the tag? If you don't set it, it will be null...

Comment: @WarrenFaith I can't thank you enough good sir :), convertview.settag(holder); should have been below the last holder. element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getTag() will be null unless you have used setTag(). It will probably work as you want if you remove the call to getTag()